# Groovy / Grails dynamically add a String type field

Tags: grails, groovy

How to add a String type field to class (i.e to all instances of that class), like grails add an id and version fields to all domain classes? If it is possible, how to specify the type of field as String / Long etc

EDIT:

The added fields are not updated in DB. how to make them persistent?

Comment: i believe a plugin does something like this for audit trails using AST   http://grails.org/plugin/audit-trail . might we worth looking at this source code

Answer (score 2):

With respect to POGO, you can use ExpandoMetaClass to add/override a property/field/constructor.

```
class Foo{
   String bar
}

//Add a field to Foo at runtime
//Type is set to String in this case
Foo.metaClass.baz = "Hello World"

//Add a method to Foo at runtime
Foo.metaClass.doSomething = {String str -> str.reverse()}

assert new Foo().baz == "Hello World"
assert new Foo().doSomething("Hello") == "olleH"
```

Comment: It wouldn't be persistent though, so not a candidate for domain class properties

Comment: @BurtBeckwith I assumed OP is referring to domain class as an example and not actually trying to add property to domain class. Was inclined more towards the "groovy" tag in the question. I may be wrong.

Comment: hm, actually i want to add some common attributes to all domain classes. how to make them persist?

Comment: @user2463026 I have not tried it but I would have extended `DefaultGrailsDomainClass` from grails-core and added the `customField` and then try to access the domain class. [Here is a discussion about the same topic](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/common-fields-in-domain-classes-td4648141.html) which might help you. I will try them myself   in the mean time as well, before giving any concrete answer. Will update my answer to reflect in context to Groovy.

Answer (score 1):

For your use case, you may be able to use normal inheritance:

```
abstract class Base {
  // common fields
  // constraints for those fields
  // etc.
}

class MyDomain extends Base {
}
```